# How to Utilize Error and Result Data Callback Simultaneously in Mongoose Express?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to use error and result data in my controller, but got a little bit confused and always got this response :

```
{
  "status": "fail",
  "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"60f943dd4bef612ae873d34\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Student\""
}
```

But i get this response when the data is not found :

```
}     
      "status": "fail",
      "message": "Cannot delete student data with id 60f943dd4bef612ae873d34. Student data was not found
}
```

My code as follows :

```
deleteOneStudent: async (req, res) => {
        const { _id } = req.params;
        
        const student = Student.findById({ _id });
        await Student.exists({ _id }, async (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    status: "fail",
                    message: err.message || "Some error occurred while deleting student data."
                });
            }
            
            if (!data) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    status: "fail",
                    message: `Cannot delete student data with id ${_id}. Student data was not found`
                });
            } else { //the code below is for removing ref from Semester document when deleting Student document 
                await Semester.updateMany({ '_id': student.semester }, { $pull: { student: student._id } }, { new: true, useFindAndModify: false })
                student.remove()
                return res.status(200).json({
                    status: "success",
                    message: "Student data was deleted successfully",
                });
            }

        })
    },
```

if I remove the first `if`, everything works fine, but I want to utilize `404` , `500` , and `200` altogether, and I have no idea using `.then()` and `.catch()` either. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks _id casting issue. You can wrap _id in `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`

```
await Student.exists({ _id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id) }, async (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    status: "fail",
                    message: err.message || "Some error occurred while deleting student data."
                });
            }
....
....
```

```
deleteOneStudent: async (req, res) => {

try{
        const { _id } = req.params;
        
        const student = Student.findById({ _id });
        await Student.exists({ _id }, async (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    status: "fail",
                    message: err.message || "Some error occurred while deleting student data."
                });
            }
            
            if (!data) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    status: "fail",
                    message: `Cannot delete student data with id ${_id}. Student data was not found`
                });
            } else { //the code below is for removing ref from Semester document when deleting Student document 
                await Semester.updateMany({ '_id': student.semester }, { $pull: { student: student._id } }, { new: true, useFindAndModify: false })
                student.remove()
                return res.status(200).json({
                    status: "success",
                    message: "Student data was deleted successfully",
                });
            }

        })
  }
  catch(error){
       return res.status(500).json({
                    status: "fail",
                    message: error,
                });
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, your answer lead to error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters`

Comment: that's because you are passing incorrect id. `60f943dd4bef612ae873d34` this is 23 digits id, MongoDB stores as 24 digits.

Comment: is it has any correlation? Because if the `req.params` just simply doesn't match, isn't it supposed to be `404` instead of `500` regardless the length?

Comment: `500` when exception happens at server side and in your code as casting failing. `404` is client side error and in your code business logic exception which is handled at `if(!data)`

Comment: oh right, i think the mistake is with me. i got the error true, but the error is in console, i want to pass it to `500` response, how i do that? The `return res.status(500).json({ status: "fail", message: err.message || "Some error occurred while deleting student data." });` did not pass the error to the client

Comment: I have updated the code. In 2nd code block I have wrapped everything in try catch and in catch block I am returning the response with the error.

Comment: So while waiting your answer, i stumbled upon `mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid()` to determine if the `_id` is valid or not and use it in `if` and place it after `{ _id }` without wrapping everything in `try catch` and i gave it `400` response. It works fine though, replacing the error of 24 hex decimal. Do you think it's good enough or maybe there's better way like your updated answer?

Comment: Yup, `mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid()` is better. I forgot about that.